# Передача значений параметров между методами без "ref" и "out" (C#)

Tags: c#, параметры

Суть задачи такова. В существующем коде бизнес-процесса в некотором методе происходит обсчет параметров, разнос их значений по БД и выход из этого метода. Метод ничего не возвращает (т.е. имеет тип `void`).

**Вопрос:** Существует ли способ передать значение параметра из этого метода в другой метод без применения модификаторов `ref` и `out` для этого параметра?

К примеру:

```
public void SomeMethod1(int i, int j)
{
   i++;
   j+=j;
}

public int SomeMethod2(int k, int m)
{
   k+=i;
   m+=j;
   return k+m;
}
```

Но самое трудное то, что нельзя (по причинам архитектуры программной среды) описать эти параметры (а именно `i` и `j`) на уровне класса. Также нельзя изменять сигнатуру метода `SomeMethod1`, т.к. на него ссылки идут из кода всего программного продукта. Но можно изменять метод `SomeMethod2` (т.к. я сам его добавляю и правлю), а также тело метода `SomeMethod1`.

Прошу помощи, кто сталкивался с подобным!

Comment: Вызывайте `SomeMethod2` из `SomeMethod1` и передавайте `i` и `j` в качестве аргументов.

Comment: Хорошая идея! Увы, и этого сделать нельзя, т.к. они находятся в разных классах (условно говоря), и как раз получение значений параметров `k` и `m` обусловлено нахождением метода `SomeMethod2` в другом классе.

Comment: А, перегрузка методов тоже запрещена? То, что подсказали в самом первом комментарии легко реализовать с помощью перегрузки. И цель будет достигнута и оригинальную версию метода сохраните.

Comment: Только её использовать и можно из всего возможного (уж извините, такова среда разработки - не буду называть; не хочу никому портить имидж CRM-системы), и я поступил схожим образом. В своём случае я использовал новый метод `public int SomeMethod3(int i, int j)` с тем же телом, что и у метода `SomeMethod1`, который просто вернет мне мои `int` (или всё что нужно), которые я и передам методу `SomeMethod2` (например, в виде какой-то коллекции).

Comment: Спасибо всем, кто отозвался! Вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 2):

Да запросто! Заведите класс-контейнер

```
class Container
{
    public int i, j;
}
```

и используйте его в качестве параметра.

```
public void SomeMethod1(Container c)
{
   c.i++;
   c.j += c.j;
}

public int SomeMethod2(Container c, int k, int m)
{
   k += c.i;
   m += c.j;
   return k + m;
}
```

Обратите внимание, что без изменения сигнатуры на данный момент `i` и `j` передаются как копии, и достать значения этих копий внутри функции без «сотрудничества» самой функции невозможно.

Ещё одной идеей могло бы быть использование глобального контейнера, но это на мой вкус очень уж грязное решение.

Comment: К сожалению, как я и писал, я не могу менять сигнатуру метода `SomeMethod1`. Если бы у меня уже среди параметров была какая-то коллекция, можно было бы поэкспериментировать, но я иначе решил эту проблему (ну, для своего случая). Смотрите 4-й комментарий к предыдущему посту. Всё равно спасибо!